# Equation number doesn't appear when the equation comes in 2 different page

Tags: equations, amsmath

I have a long equation which I break to lines by using either `align` or `split`.
Unfortunately in my pdf file, half of this equation comes in one page and rest is in the next page and that is the reason, the equation number does not appear though the order of equation is preserved. Also, I can't refer to this equation though it has a label.
How can I have the equation number after the equation? Note that I have to use `\scriptstyle` to make the equation fit on page width.

Here is a smaller example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
{\scriptstyle
 \begin{equation}  \label{Model}
 \begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^{n}&\Biggl\{\Big[\sum_{k=1}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t-1}\exp(\rho(j)+\beta^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}-\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t}\exp(\rho(j)+\beta^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}\pi_{\eta}^{(k)}(\varepsilon_i)\Big]^{1-\delta_i} \times \notag \\
&\Biggl[\left(\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t-1}\exp(\rho(j)+\beta^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}-\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t}\exp(\rho(j)+\beta^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}\pi_{\eta}^{(1)}(\varepsilon_i)\right)^{I_{(\varepsilon_i_i=1)}} \times \notag \\
&\left(\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t-1}\exp(\rho(j)+\beta^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}-\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t}\exp(\rho(j)+\beta^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}\pi_{\eta}^{(2)}(\varepsilon_i)\right)^{I_{(\varepsilon_i_i=2)}}\Biggr]^{\delta_i}.p_i\Biggr\}^{W_i\xi_i} \times \notag\\
  &\Biggl\{\Big[\sum_{k=1}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t-1}\exp(\rho(j)+\phi^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}-\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t}\exp(\rho(j)+\phi^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}\pi_{\eta}^{(k)}(\varepsilon_i)\Big]^{1-\delta_i} \times \notag \\
&\Biggl[\left(\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t-1}\exp(\rho(j)+\phi^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}-\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t}\exp(\rho(j)+\phi^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}\pi_{\eta}^{(1)}(\varepsilon_i)\right)^{I_{(\varepsilon_i_i=1)}} \times \notag \\
&\left(\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t-1}\exp(\rho(j)+\phi^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}-\left(\frac{1}{\nu (\sum_{j=1}^{t}\exp(\rho(j)+\phi^TZ_i))+1}\right)^{1/\nu}\pi_{\eta}^{(2)}(\varepsilon_i)\right)^{I_{(\varepsilon_i_i=2)}}\Biggr]^{\delta_i}.(1-p_i)\Biggr\}^{W_i(1-\xi_i)}.
\end{align}
\end{equation}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using "align", but I check "split " too, and it was working.

Comment: The code as it stands will throw dozens of errors. Anyway, if you use `equation` and `split` all the `\notag`s will suppress numbering.

Comment: the \notag s are in middle lines to avoid having multiple equation numbers.

Comment: Even when I write my equation in align environment only, the equation doesn't appear at all. If I remove the \scriptstyle it will appear but doesn't fit in my page. I though the combination of equation+align may help.

Comment: you can not have a `align` inside `equation` that surely gives an error?

Comment: The example posted makes multiple errors and just typesets (1)

Comment: `\scriptstyle`  outside mathematics does not make things smaller, it just generates an error. Does your real document have `\scriptsize` (which is a font size command)

Comment: In my .txt file, I have only align not a combination of both align and equation. I do have {\scriptstyle \begin{align}  the equatin \end{align}   } and it does make the equation smaller and fit to the page.

Comment: Even using \tiny, it won't fit the page.  You can save a lot of space using \frac{1}{\nu} instead of 1/nu (for example), but not enough.  Also, I don't know what \varepsilon_i_i=2 is supposed to look like, but it also gives an error.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the advice.  Sorry, \varepsilon_i_i=2 is a mistake, it should be \varepsilon_i=2.

Comment: use `\footnotesize` (a command usable in text mode) instead of `\scriptstyle` (relevant only within math).

Comment: But not `\varepsilon_{i=2}` ?

Comment: \footnotesize works better, though still I have no equation number. Thanks Barbara

Comment: John, you are right, it is not \varepsilon_{i=2}... It is \varepsilon_i=2

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a building block such as `split` or `aligned` (`align` is not permitted) inside `equation` does not allow for a page break.  Instead use `align` as the only environment, and insert `\notag` to suppress unwanted numbering.  Instead of reducing the size of the equation, introduce notation for large repeated expressions:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}

\vspace{15cm}

{\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align} \label{Model}
  \prod_{i=1}^{n}
  &\biggl\{
    \biggl[
    \sum_{k=1}^{2}
    x(\beta,i,t-1)-x(\beta,i,t)\pi_{\eta}^{(k)}(\varepsilon_i)
    \biggr]^{1-\delta_i}
    \notag \\
  &\qquad \times
    \Bigl[
    \bigl(
    x(\beta,i,t-1) - x(\beta,i,t)\pi_{\eta}^{(1)}(\varepsilon_i)
    \bigr)^{I_{(\varepsilon_i=1)}}
     \notag \\
  &\hspace{4em} \times
    \bigl(
    x(\beta,i,t-1) -x(\beta,i,t)\pi_{\eta}^{(2)}(\varepsilon_i)
    \bigr)^{I_{(\varepsilon_i=2)}}
    \Bigr]^{\delta_i} \cdot p_i
    \biggr\}^{W_i\xi_i} \notag \\
  &\times
    \biggl\{
    \Bigl[
    \sum_{k=1}^{2}
    x(\phi,i,t-1) - x(\phi,i,t)\pi_{\eta}^{(k)}(\varepsilon_i)
    \Bigr]^{1-\delta_i} \notag \\
  &\qquad \times
    \Bigl[
    \bigl(
    x(\phi,i,t-1)- x(\phi,i,t)\pi_{\eta}^{(1)}(\varepsilon_i)
    \bigr)^{I_{(\varepsilon_i=1)}} \notag \\
  &\hspace{4em} \times
    \bigl(
    x(\phi,i,t-1)-x(\phi,i,t)\pi_{\eta}^{(2)}(\varepsilon_i)
    \bigr)^{I_{(\varepsilon_i=2)}}
    \Bigr]^{\delta_i} \cdot (1-p_i)
    \biggr\}^{W_i(1-\xi_i)},
   \label{Model}
\end{align}
}
where \( x(A,i,t) = (\nu(\sum_{j=1}^{t} \exp(\rho(j)+A^{T}Z_{i}))+1)^{-1/\nu} \)
\end{document}
```